# File-like data sent using python requests

Tags: python, request, python-requests

I'm sending files to an API using python requests

```
    files = [("file", open(path_to_file, 'rb'))]
    headers = {"Authorization": "bearer " + CLIENT.token}
    response = requests.request(
        "POST",
        SETTINGS.URL_FILE_STORAGE,
        headers=headers,
        files=files
        # files= [('file',catalogo)],
    )
```

which throws a 202. But nevertheless, if I send the file as bytes, that is  `type(file) = Bytes` The API throws a 500. What's the connection between send file data as `open(path_file, 'rb')` vs send data as Bytes?.

Answer (score 4):

Which version of Requests are you using? In the current master branch at least there should be no difference. If you track down what happens to the `files` list in `requests.request`, you'll find that [arguments of type `str`, `bytes` and `bytearray` get passed through as data](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/eedd67462819f8dbf8c1c32e77f9070606605231/requests/models.py#L156), whereas for file-like objects, the `.read()` method is executed and the result of that is used instead.

So the following should produce the same request as your code:

```py
    files = [("file", open(path_to_file, 'rb').read())] # Get file contents
    headers = {"Authorization": "bearer " + CLIENT.token}
    response = requests.request(
        "POST",
        SETTINGS.URL_FILE_STORAGE,
        headers=headers,
        files=files
        # files= [('file',catalogo)],
    )
```

I would be fairly surprised if the API responds differently to these two versions.

But if it does, and you have data of type `bytes` that you need to turn into a file-like object, you can simply use `io`:

```py
import io
```

```py
    files = [("file", io.BytesIO(data))]
    headers = {"Authorization": "bearer " + CLIENT.token}
    response = requests.request(
        "POST",
        SETTINGS.URL_FILE_STORAGE,
        headers=headers,
        files=files
        # files= [('file',catalogo)],
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!, The problem was in the API, because when I was sending the file as bytes, requests tried to guess the file name (with its extension), 
in bytes mode the name was set as "file", and the API only supports specific extensions then it fell. I would have liked to receive another type of error, I dont know 415?. Thank you very much

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: I'm confused: is there a typo in both code snippets? At line 0: It looks like you open a round bracket but forget to close it.

Comment: @HAL9000 Yes, that’s a typo that was copied from the question’s code. Should be a tuple inside a list.

Comment: ok, good: typo fixed